# Populate listbox item in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a list box item that i have changed the list style to combo box.

I need to populate the combo box with values from a table.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Just populate it as a normal listbox like so:

```
declare 
  v_rg_id recordgroup; 
  V_errorcode number; 
Begin 
  v_rg_id :=find_group('xyz'); 

  if id_null(v_rg_id) then 
    v_rg_id := create_group_from_query('xyz',
                'Select distinct ename, ename from emp'); 
    v_errorcode := populate_group(v_rg_id); 

    If v_errorcode=0 then 
      message('Record group populated with data'); 
    else 
      message('V_errorcode is:' || v_errorcode); 
    end if; 
  End if; 

  populate_list('Last_name_list',v_rg_id); 
end;
```